# Using the property "onto" in the proof

Tags: general-topology, functions

**Definition(Minimal open set):** A proper nonempty open subset $U$ of a topological space $X$ is said to be a minimal open set if any open set which is contained in $U$ is $\emptyset$ or $U$.

**Definition(Minimal irresolute map):** Let $X$ and $Y$ be the topological spaces. A map $f : X → Y$ is called ***minimal irresolute*** if $f^{-1}(M)$ is minimal open set in X for every minimal open set $M$ in $Y$.

**Definition(minimal $T_{0}$ Space):** A topological space $X$ is said to be $minimal-T_{0}$ space if for any two distinct points $x,y$ in $X$, there exists a minimal open set containing one of them but not the other.

[image]

I do not understand where we used that $f$ is an onto function. When we look at the definition;

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called ***onto*** if for all $y$ in $Y$ there is a $x$ in $X$ such that $f(x) = y$. That is, all elements in $Y$ are used.

So, I think if $f$ was not an onto function in this theorem, nothing would change. Is it right?

Thank you..

Comment: Actually the author uses the inverse of the function (not just the inverse image, they use the inverse function) but I think you don’t really need to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used in the middle of the proof when $y_1\in M$ and they calculate $f^{-1}(y_1)$. If $f$ were not onto then that inverse might not be defined for the whole neighbourhood $M$.

Comment: if $y_{1}\in M$ then $f^{-1}(y_{1}) \in f^{-1}(M)$. It's always true, isn't it? Is $f$ supposed to be onto for this?

Comment: No, if $f$ is not onto, there exists at least one element $y \in M$ such that $f^{-1}(y) = \varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you so much